# firestore security rules: allow logged in user to update field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following firestore security rules

```
match /users/{user} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow create: if request.resource.id == request.auth.uid;            
    
  match /replies {
    allow update: if request.auth != null;
  }
}
```

my understanding from the firestore security rules doc is that the two rules are independent of each other. However, a logged in user gets a permission denied message when trying to update the `/user/{user}/replies` field. It doesn't matter if I nest the rule or not. It still gets denied.  (it also doesn't work in Rules Playground in Firebase console)

what am I doing wrong?

my client code is as follows:

```js
const processNewMessage = async (evt, newMessage) => {
  myMessage.value = myMessage.value.trim();

  if (evt.srcElement.textContent === "send") {
    if (replying.value === true) {
      const message = {
        originalMessage: {
          text: props.selectedMessage.text,
          photoUrl: props.selectedMessage.photoUrl,
        },
        reply: {
          user: uid,
          userDisplayName: auth.currentUser.displayName,
          userName: userName.value,
          text: newMessage,
          createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
          g: { geohash: geohash.value, geopoint: myLocation },
          photoUrl: photoUrl,
        },
      };

      await updateDoc(doc(db, `users/${props.selectedMessage.user}`), {
        replies: arrayUnion(message),
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client code that doesn't work the way you expect.  You could be doing something wrong there - we need to see that your rules match your code.  Your code example should allow anyone to reproduce the behavior you observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security rules work on a document-level. Your code is trying to update the `replies` **array** in the `users` document, which is not allowed by any of your rules.

The `match /replies` in your rules applies to a `replies` subcollection under the `users` document. It has no effect on **fields** in the `users` document.

---

If you want the owner to update their entire document, and other signed in users to only update the `replies` field, you'll have to allow that in the rule on `users`.

Something like this:

```
match /users/{user} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow create: if request.resource.id == request.auth.uid;            
  allow update: if request.auth != null && 
    request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["replies"])
  ;
}
```

For more on how this works, see the release notes for the [map `diff` function](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020).